# reduced causal adverbial clauses in the second part of a sentence

Tags: clauses, participle-clauses

Can we use a causal adverbial clause in the second part of a sentence? if so, I wonder if I want to use an adverbial clause of causality in the second part of a sentence, should I use a comma before the adverbial clause?
For instance, can contract this sentence

> Individuals sometimes find themselves drowned in a mountain of tasks **since they procrastinate** their non-essential yet needed-to-be-done-someday duties to the last minute.

```
to:
```

> Individuals sometimes find themselves drowned in a mountain of tasks **procrastinating** their non-essential yet needed-to-be-done-someday duties to the last minute.
>   I would also really appreciate it if you could provide me with some explanation.

Comment: Your second attempt is far less idiomatic than the first, which I don't like much anyway. Note that transitive ***to procrastinate [something]*** isn't very common (many people would probably see your usage as an error), and stylistically speaking it would be much better to say they found themselves ***drowning***, not ***drowned***. So a more natural phrasing might be ***People** sometimes find themselves **drowning** in a mountain of tasks, **if** they **put off** their non-essential yet needed-to-be-done-someday duties to the last minute*. But it's all about stylistic choices and opinions.

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I know what you say.However, I don't want to utilize this sentence in any particular text. I just used it as an example to understand causal adverbial clause more, so if you could elaborate on it, I will be really grateful. Incidentally, thanks for your helpful note on **drowning**.